# swift 3 - create entry with relationship

Tags: macos, swift3, xcode8

i working the first time with relationships in core data.
what i have now:

```
let appdelegate = NSApplication.shared().delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = appdelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext


// Create Person
let entityPerson = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Person", in: context)
let newPerson = NSManagedObject(entity: entityPerson!, insertInto: context)
newPerson.setValue("Max", forKey: "name")

// Create Book
let entityBooks = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Book", in: context)
let newBooks = NSManagedObject(entity: entityBooks!, insertInto: context)
newBooks.setValue("My Book", forKey: "title")

// Assign Book to Person
newPerson.setValue(NSSet(object: newBooks), forKey: "relationship")
```

This works fine.
It creates a person and a book, which will assign to the created person.

But now the next problem:
How can I assign a new book entry to an person, which is already available in core data?

**UPDATE**

This is my Core Data
[image]

[image]

**Person.swift**

```
@objc(Person)
public class Person: NSManagedObject {

}

extension Person {

    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var books: Book?

}
```

**Book.swift**

```
@objc(Book)
public class Book: NSManagedObject {

}

extension Book {


    @NSManaged public var title: String?

}
```

**I created the Person Max**

```
 let appdelegate = NSApplication.shared().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appdelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        // Create Person
        let entityPerson = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Person", in: context)
        let newPerson = NSManagedObject(entity: entityPerson!, insertInto: context)
        newPerson.setValue("Max", forKey: "name")

do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {}
```

**Result in Core Data:**

[image]

**Then i created a book with the title "My Book" which should assign to Max**

```
let appdelegate = NSApplication.shared().delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = appdelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext


        // Create Book
        let entityBook = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Book", in: context)
        let newBook = NSManagedObject(entity: entityBook!, insertInto: context)
        newBook.setValue("My Book2", forKey: "title")


        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Person")
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", "Max")

        do {
            let result = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Person]

            if let person = result.first {
                person.setValue(NSSet(object: newBook), forKey: "books")
            }
        } catch { }


        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {}
```

**Core Data Result**

[image]

PERFECT !!

**But now i will create a second book "My Book 2" which should assign to Max (with the same code above but with book title "My Book 2"**

**The result of core data**

[image]

I hope you unterstand the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to perform a fetch to check if the person is available.

Then assign the person to the book (to-one relationship) for example

```
let personName = "John"
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Person>(entityName: "Person")
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", personName)
fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
do {
    let persons = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    if let person = persons.first {
        newBook.person = person
    }
} catch {
   print(error)
}
```

The code takes advantage of the Swift 3 generic types.

**Edit:**

The declaration of the `NSManagedObject` subclasses are wrong.

According to your model `Person` must be

```
extension Person {
    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var books: NSSet
}
```

and `Books` must be

```
extension Book {
    @NSManaged public var title: String?
    @NSManaged public var person: Person?
}
```

Consider to make at least the `name` and `title` attributes non-optional.

---

PS: Since you are using `NSManagedObject` subclasses you can use the property directly with dot notation rather then KVC

```
newPerson.name = "Max"
```

Comment: thanks, but one problem. the first run works perfectly. it will be create the book which will assign to the person with first name "Max". but if i run the Programm again, it will be create a new book, which will assign to the Person Max = all okay, but first book lost the relationship. any idea?

Comment: I answered your question but I have no idea what your relationship logic is (one-to-one or one-to-many) . Maybe you need other checks with `if - else` expressions. In Swift 3 it's highly recommended to use `NSManagedObject` subclasses for convenience reasons.

Comment: i updated my post. the logic is: Entity Person: relationship to Book (one to many), Entity Book: relationship to Person (one to one)

Comment: thank you very much. but your modifications brings the same result :(

Comment: The code is supposed to work according to your model. Are the one-to-one and one-to-many relationships set properly? See the edited code: Now the person is assigned to the book.

Comment: here you can download my Xcode project: https://www.file-upload.com/iq7l11kikwo5 - can you check it please ? :)

Comment: I'm sorry I don't visit those ads contaminated portals.

Comment: Do you use Dropbox or similar serious webspace?

Comment: Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8PBtMQt9GdON1Q2ak5tcDJieHM

Comment: That worked. The project does not use the code I suggested in the answer

Comment: First of all my code uses a generic fetch request and as already mentioned in another comment: ***See the edited code: Now the person is assigned to the book***

Comment: Oh come on. Read and compare every line. For example you got *person.setValue(NSSet(object: newBook), forKey: "relationship")* - I wrote *newBook.person = person*. You got *let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Person")* - I wrote *let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Person>(entityName: "Person")* There are more differences.

Comment: oh sry, i send you the wrong version of project: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8PBtMQt9GdOTGtrQ0lsMk5xZlU

Comment: The code works! Not related but you have to add `as! Book` at the end of the line `let newBook ...`. The issue is most likely that you create a person then create a book then (re-)fetch the person. That does not work because the context must be saved after creating the person to be able to refetch it.