# One to Many Relationship Core Data fetch Data

Tags: swift, core-data, one-to-many

There are a lot of questions regarding this topic but I can not get it to work.

In this answer of vadian he gets the value with two repeated loops:

1. [swift 3 - core data relationship - fetch data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43867033/swift-3-core-data-relationship-fetch-data)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43846785/8887336

It does not work for my code and I can not figure out why.

This is my code:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

struct HobbiesCollection {
  let typ: String
  let location: String
}


class LoadData{
  class func load(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    let persons = ["Owen", "Greg"]
    let futbal = HobbiesCollection(typ: "futbal", location: "stadium")
    let swimming = HobbiesCollection(typ: "swimming", location: "pool")
    let collection = [persons[0]: swimming, persons[1]: futbal]

    for x in collection {
      let person = Person(context: context)
      let hobbiesCD = Hobbies(context: context)
      person.name = x.key
      hobbiesCD.typ = x.value.typ
      hobbiesCD.location = x.value.location

      person.addToToHobbies(hobbiesCD)

      do {
        try context.save()
      } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
      }
    }

    let fetch: NSFetchRequest<Person> = Person.fetchRequest()
    var result = [Person]()
    do {
      result = try context.fetch(fetch)
    } catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    for y in result {
      print("Persons:", y.name!)
      for x in y.toHobbies! {
        let location = x.location Error: "Value of type 'Any' has no member 'location'"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get the error:

> Value of type 'Any' has no member 'location'

My two classes with Core Data:

```
extension Person {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Person> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Person>(entityName: "Person")
    }

    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var toHobbies: NSSet?

}

// MARK: Generated accessors for toHobbies
extension Person {

    @objc(addToHobbiesObject:)
    @NSManaged public func addToToHobbies(_ value: Hobbies)

    @objc(removeToHobbiesObject:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromToHobbies(_ value: Hobbies)

    @objc(addToHobbies:)
    @NSManaged public func addToToHobbies(_ values: NSSet)

    @objc(removeToHobbies:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromToHobbies(_ values: NSSet)

}
extension Hobbies {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Hobbies> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Hobbies>(entityName: "Hobbies")
    }

    @NSManaged public var typ: String?
    @NSManaged public var location: String?
    @NSManaged public var toPerson: Person?

}
```

Also I have a further question regarding Predicate.
If I do a predicate fetch like this:

> fetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", person1)

If I would have more than one hobby in my example, is it possible to get all hobbies with location = stadium for example with a second predicate parameter instead for looking for these hobbies with location = stadium of person1 with a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

toHobbies property is NSSet of Any so you need to typecast it or each x in your loop.

For predicates you can use key-paths like “toHobbies.location = %@“